# Intel ESG tutorials and examples needed

Tags: mule, intel, esb, mule-studio, mule-component

I am looking for Intel ESG (Intel Expressway Service Gateway) I have to work on this so I am looking for any documentation or tutorial links.
Please if anyone uses this or know about something on it Please help me.

Comment: Upvoted because the documentation isn't actually on the MuleSoft website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MuleSoft has very good developer community and lot of online resources available. If you go to [developer](https://developer.mulesoft.com/) site for MuleSoft you will get everything that you want. Browse through sub-menu of 'Resources' and 'Community' menu. 
MuleSoft [documentation](https://docs.mulesoft.com/) is also comprehensive and contains samples in some cases.

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the question. I have looked thoroughly through the Mulesoft site and there is no documentation there for the ESG devices. Unless they are under a completely different name.